# Как отнести полученный цвет в RGB к основному

Tags: c++, алгоритм, opencv, цвета

Есть набор цветов в формате RGB, например, "150 145 16". Мне нужно узнать к какому основному цвет отнести и соответственно выполнить некие действия например: если это желтый или все его оттенки то выполнить некое действие. Проблема заключается в том что я не понимаю как можно отнести цвет к какому-то основному как в примере желтому. Если кратко, то нужно следующее нужно определить к какому цвету из:

- синий.
- зеленый
- красный
- желтый.
- фиолетовый
- коричневый.
- черный
- серый

можно отнести полученный цвет в RGB ?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Самый простой способ — посчитать разницу между RGB-каналами образцов и тестового цвета. Примерно так:

```
// класс цвета
class color {
    public:
    string _name;
    char _r, _g, _b;

    // конструктор
    color (string name, char r, char g, char b) {
        _name = name;
        _r = r;
        _g = g;
        _b = b;
    }

    // сравнение с другим цветом
    int distanceTo (color &another) {
        return (abs(another._r - _r) + abs(another._g - _g) + abs(another._b - _b));
    }
}

...

// набор цветов для сравнения
vector<color> sources;
sources.push_back(color("red", 255, 0, 0));
sources.push_back(color("green", 0, 255, 0));
sources.push_back(color("blue", 0, 0, 255));
sources.push_back(color("yellow", 255, 255, 0));
sources.push_back(color("purple", 255, 0, 255));
sources.push_back(color("black", 0, 0, 0));
sources.push_back(color("white", 255, 255, 255));

// интересующий цвет
color test("test", 64, 32, 32);

// лучшее совпадение
color *best = nullptr;
int dst = 1024;

// поиск
for (auto it = sources.begin; it != sources.end(); it++) {
    int current = (*it).distanceTo(test);
    if (current < dst) {
        dst = current;
        best = *(*it);
    }
}

// вывод ближайшего совпадения
cout << "Best match: " << best->name << "\n";
```

---

Более точный результат можно получить сравнивая цвета по [оттенку, яркости и насыщенности](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSV_%28%D1%86%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%29). Но в большинстве случаев хватит и сравнения по обычным каналам.

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас попробую использовать данный способ в проекте но судя с логики кода должно быть именно то что нужно.

Comment: как оказалось не совсем подходит данный вариант или возможно не правильно задал условие например цвет 
197 242 169 данный код относит к желтый, и еще вопрос что означает  строка int dst = 1024; и как она влияет на отнесения цвета.

Comment: @JonniHelpers а Вы отнесения к какому цвету ожидали? Если другие цвета не заданы, то это самый близкий. `int dst = 1024` — мы ищем самую маленькую разницу между цветами, она сохраняется в эту переменную. Соответственно, изначально в ней должны быть значение, которое больше любого расстояния между двумя цветами. Как минимум, это 256*3 = 768.

Comment: @JonniHelpers для большей точности можно использовать больше базовых цветов. Например, если сделать розовый, тогда 197 242 169 будет отнесён к нему. Если же нужен базис из менее десятка цветов, как в вопросе, то лучше использовать модель HSV. Весь код будет почти такой же, только в конструкторе или до него сделать перевод цвета. Использование оттенка у цветов без насыщенности (вроде чёрного) вряд ли помешает, но и с этой проблемой можно будет справиться, если нужно.

Comment: извините не тот цвет указал вот цвет 167, 154, 183 который похож наиболее к фиолетовый данный код относит к желтый.
Была мысль об таком алгоритме 
полученный цвет в RGB конвертировать в HSV затем  в параметры устанавливать значение  S  = 100  V=50 получаем а для H ставим проверку диапазона. получаем точный цвет даже если он изначально затемненный, но проблема в том, что непонятно как определять серый и черный цвета.

Comment: @JonniHelpers если цветов не много, то есть, чёрный и серый единственные проблемные, то перед проверкой цвета их можно выявлять отдельно. Например, если яркость очень низкая, то цвет чёрный. А если насыщенность низкая, то серый.

Comment: Да, Вы правы, должно получится,  пробую реализовать такой алгоритм, спасибо за подсказку. будем пробовать

Answer (score 4):

Переведите цвет в [HSV](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSV_%28%D1%86%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%29), затем посмотрите на значение H - оно как раз и означает цвет.

Не получится с HSV, посмотрите [HSL](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL).

Comment: Ваш способ не учитывает яркости и насыщенности — в вопросе фигурируют чёрный и серый цвета.

Comment: Просмотрел, данный вариант, но тут нужно будет смотреть не только на значение H, так как серый и черный имеют H значение "0" если можно как то узнать какие диапазоны задавать для каждого из основных цветов в HSV?  тоесь например если значение от 0-40 то это серый черный но какие диапазоны задать для для S  и V.

Comment: @JonniHelpers посмотрите тогда модель HSL.

Answer (score 2):

```
h, s, v = rgb_to_hsv(r, g, b)

if s < 0.25 // или какая константа больше нравится
  if v < 0.25
    черный
  elsif v > 0.75
    белый
  else
    серый
  end
else
  { какой цвет из радуги ближе всего по  abs(h1-h2) mod 360 }
end
```

---

Либо [https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Формула_цветового_отличия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D1%86%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%8F)